# Downloading or rendering on an Iframe depending on app Logic in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I have an angular JS app on which I download a pdf file and then create a blob from it. Like this:

```
vm.fileData = new ApiDownloadFile({fileId: 1});
  return vm.fileData.$query()
    .then(function(response) {

      try{

        console.log("Try..." + new Date());
        $log.log(response);
        var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(response.Body.data);
        $log.log(arrayBufferView);
        var file = new Blob( [arrayBufferView], {type: response.ContentType});
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        link.download =  response.fileName;
        link.click();
        console.log("After..." + new Date());
        console.log("GENERATED LINK: "+link.href);
        //PDFObject.embed(link.href, "#my-container");
      }
      catch(e) {

        console.log("Execption...");
        // TypeError old chrome and FF
        window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
          window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
          window.MozBlobBuilder ||
          window.MSBlobBuilder;

        if (e.name == 'TypeError' && window.BlobBuilder) {
          var bb = new BlobBuilder();
          bb.append(response.Body.data);
          var file = bb.getBlob("image/jpeg");
          var link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

          link.download = "1.jpg";
          //link.click();

        }
        else if (e.name == "InvalidStateError") {
          // InvalidStateError (tested on FF13 WinXP)
          var jpeg = new Blob(response.Body.data, {type: "image/jpeg"});
        }
        else {
          // We're screwed, blob constructor unsupported entirely
        }

      }
    },function(err) {
      $log.log(err);
    });
};
```

I can donwload the file easily by creating an 'a' element and then clicking it. However I would like to be able to either download it on the browser or render it on an Iframe I have in my view. The logic should be something like this:

```
if download == true:
    create the <a> element and click it to download file.
else:
    render the pdf on an iframe and don´t download on browser.
```

However I´m not able to get the blob URL to be rendered on the Iframe. I´m using PDFObject to visualize the PDF. Can anyone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your page

```
<iframe ng-if="IframeManager.Url" ng-src="{{ IframeManager.Url }}"></iframe>
```

Then in your controller add

```
$scope.Download = true;

$scope.IframeManager = {
    Show: function (url) {
         $scope.IframeManager.Url = url;
        },
    Hide: function () {
         $scope.IframeManager.Url = null;
    }
};
```

So if you want to show the file you do your preview routine blob conversion and get the url

```
if ($scope.Download) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    link.download =  response.fileName;
    link.click();
    console.log("After..." + new Date());
    console.log("GENERATED LINK: "+link.href);
} else {
    $scope.IframeManager.Show(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the Iframe does not display with the blob url. I´ve also tried giving the url to an embed but it also shows blank. However, if I try an external url suchs as: http://example.com/myPdf.pdf the file displays correctly.  This is the iframe:  `<iframe ng-if="ctrl.IframeManager.Url" ng-src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A4000/fd2c622b-c788-4679-9985-9e9238d086fd" class="ng-scope" src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A4000/fd2c622b-c788-4679-9985-9e9238d086fd"></iframe>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally got it working. The problem was with the content-type header of my http response. I had it with application/octet-stream which made it download. I changed it to application/pdf and it now works great :)

Comment: I'm happy I could be of help. Happy coding :)